# Rotate game object by clicking a button

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, unityscript, gameobject

I have an object and 2 GUI texture buttons. I want to rotate the object to the left when I press the left button and to the right while pressing the other one.

Any ideas ?

I have a script that works when I drag my object. I will post the important part:

```c#
function Start () 
{
  var angles = transform.eulerAngles;
  x = angles.y;    

  // Make the rigid body not change rotation
  if (rigidbody)
    rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;    
}

function LateUpdate () 
{   
    if (isMouseOverGuiTexture()) return;  

    if (target && Input.GetMouseButton(0)) 
    {  
         //0.1 represents the sensitivity of the mouse
         x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSpeed *0.1; //x rotation
         //y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed *0.1;  //y rotation
         //y = ClampAngle(y, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);                
         var rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0);
         var position = rotation * Vector3(0.900528, 8.829305, -distance+0.49548)+ target.position;

         transform.rotation = rotation;
         transform.position = position;
    }
}
```

Comment: What API?  Looks like javascript?

Comment: unity 3d and the code it's javascript.

Comment: i edited my question and added the answer to it. sorry if i've done something wrong.

Comment: I don't understand, is this a question or solved?

Comment: it was a question but after i found the answer i posted here too.

Comment: You can post answers to your own questions instead.

Answer (score 0):

(Question answered in the comments. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I solved it by using the following :
>
> ```js
> var imageLeft: Texture2D; // drag the left button image here
> var imageRight: Texture2D; // right button image
> var speed: float = 60; // rotate speed in degrees per second
> private var rotLeft = false; // object rotates left if true
> private var rotRight = false; // object rotates right if true;
>
> function OnGUI()
> {
>     rotLeft = GUI.RepeatButton(Rect(10,10,200,200), imageLeft);
>     rotRight = GUI.RepeatButton(Rect(230,10,200,200), imageRight);
> }
>
> function Update()
> {    
>     if (rotLeft) transform.Rotate(0, -speed*Time.deltaTime, 0);
>     if (rotRight) transform.Rotate(0, speed*Time.deltaTime, 0);
> }
> ```
>
> I don't know which value `Time.deltaTime` assumes inside `OnGUI` - it should be the time since last `OnGUI`, but I'm not sure. To avoid problems, I placed the real rotation in `Update` and used two control booleans (`rotLeft` and `rotRight`) to communicate with `OnGUI`.